# Incomplete Pattern Matching in f#

Tags: compilation, f#, f#-interactive, f#-3.0, runtime-compilation

Consider the following code:

```
let list1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;
let getThird3 = function 
  |[] ->[];
  | _::_::l3::t -> t;;
getThird3 list1;
```

When pasted on terminal running fsharpi it gives me this error

```
> let list1 = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5];;

val list1 : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]

> let getThird3 = function 
-  |[] ->[];
-  | _::_::l3::t -> t;;

let getThird3 = function 
----------------^^^^^^^^

/Users/nickolasmorales/stdin(17,17): warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value '[_;_]' may indicate a     case not covered by the pattern(s).

val getThird3 : _arg1:'a list -> 'a list
```

Any suggestions? I tried using both: only TAB and space but it doesn't recognize anything after the function.

Comment: Can you clarify what you expect as output? As it is based on your question and comments on the one answer here, I don't know what it is you're wanting.

Comment: BTW, you're missing a second semicolon on the last line (`getThird3 list1;` should be `getThird3 list1;;`). That might be why, even when you correct your function so it handles lists with one or two items as input, you're still not seeing the results. F# doesn't need semicolons between expressions, but the F# interactive interpreter uses **double** semicolons between expressions so it knows when you're done with input. (Because **single** semicolons are a valid operator, used in lists).

Answer (score 3):

This is just a warning:

if you do `getThird3 [1;2]` you will get a matchfailureexception.

The warning has to pick somewhere specific as a base for the warning and the `function` is probably as good as anywhere else.

To remove the warning I would change the match to

```
| _::_::l3::t -> t;;
| _ -> failwith "not a long enough list"
```

Comment: so how do i get my answer?

Comment: for what - the code as written will work correctly - try doing something like `getThird3 [1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9]`

Comment: it works with the failwith! thank you! so how do i avoid warning like that and get an answer?

Comment: You avoid the warning by covering all match cases